# Compute filter output with given values of $n$

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, homework

> \begin{align}
> x[n] &=\begin{cases}
>  1& \text{for}\quad n \ge 0\\
> 0& \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}\\
> h[n] &= \delta[n] - \delta[n-1]\\
> y[n] &= x[n]*h[n]
> \end{align}
>
> Find the values of $y[-1]$, $y[0]$, $y[1]$, $y[2]$.

I thought $\delta[0] = 1$ and $\delta[n] = 0$ otherwise, and that $y[n] = x[k]h[n-k]$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
n&x[n]&d[n]&d[n-1]&h[n]&y[n]\\\hline
-1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\\hline
0&1&1&0&1&1\\\hline
1& 1 & 0 & 1 & -1&-1\\\hline
2& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\\hline
\end{array}

So I put $\text{ 0  1  -1 0 }$ as my answer but apparently that's wrong. What did I mess up? Did I misinterpret the meaning of $\delta[n]$?

Answer (score 3):

Your impulse response is $h[n]=\delta [n] - \delta [n-1]$, so it basically takes a copy of the input and then substracts to it a delayed version of the former. When $x[n]=u[n]$, the output signal is:

$$y[n] = u[n] - u[n-1]$$

This means that we have a step function (i.e. it is equal to $1$ for $n \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise), and we substract to it a shifted step (i.e. it is equal to $1$ for $n \geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise). Therefore, $\forall n \geq 1$ we are cancelling out the two signals ($1-1=0$). This leaves us with only one not-zero value, which happens to be at the origin. So the output turns out to be

$$y[n]=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } n = 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{otherwise }
 \end{array}
\right. \implies y[n]=\delta[n]$$